# Random choppy tweens

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm programming a basic game in AS3 and Deploying it through Air. There's a maximum of 7 sprites tweening at one time.

When testing the game the tweens run smoothly 90% of the time, however the other 10% of the time I get choppy tweens where it appears to be dropping frames. I would have thought if it was something in the code chewing up resources that this issue would happen 100% of the time.

Is this a known issue? Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: Normally, if Flash Player cannot draw all the frames at the given framerate, it drops framerate. However, if a timeline contains a synced sound (I think it is calles streaming in the sound frame properties, but not sure), this timeline can actually drop frames in order to keep up with the sound. Alternately, that might be a result of messing with **gotoAndPlay**s, but there is no telling since you didn't provided any code.

Comment: I should have been more clear on this issue. When I test the game, from the get go I'll do a specific move with the sprites (move from a-b) and it will run smoothly. I'll then close and test again with the same exact move and it will run choppy. It was running at 30fps so I upped it to 60fps and there has been no issues, everything is smooth 100% of the time.

Comment: Are you sure Flash is the problem? Flash uses CPU to render things, if your PC is busy doing something else (like, maybe, cleaning up disk cache after the previous run) then every process out there could experience performance difficulties, not just Flash.

Comment: Yeah, that did originally cross my mind. It makes sense. I just wanted to put it out there in case it was a known issue but I'm leaning towards my PC being the culprit. 

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: You should debug your app heavily. Test for say `Tween` instances, maybe you're creating more than a single tween per changing object, these hog up CPU doing actually nothing, maybe you create too many of other objects.